# Bitnami lampstack install libapache2-mod-proxy-html

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp

I was trying to install libapache2-mod-proxy-html on a Bitnami Lampstack by using

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

However, when I add the following line to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
```

I get the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 114 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/bitnami/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_html.so into server: /opt/bitnami/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_html.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to install the module properly on Bitnami Lampstack?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own silly question. Put absolute path to loadModule statement resolves the problem

`LoadModule proxy_html_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_html.so`